# CSS on text after input tag

Tags: css

If I have the following html code, how do I put css styling for the "Double Bed" text?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="room_type_uids[]" value="1" style="line-height: 8;height: 20px;">Double Bed<br />
```

Comment: Wrap the text in a span tag or use whatever it's container is as the CSS selector and then override styles for the input if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot style that text unless you've wrapped the text inside some container element. Possible senarios are..

Either wrap the entire thing in an element say `div` and than you can do something like

```
<div class="wrap">
   <input type="checkbox" name="room_type_uids[]" value="1" style="line-height: 8;height: 20px;">Double Bed<br />
</div>

.wrap {
   color: #f00;
}
```

**OR**

Simply wrap the text inside a `span` tag...

```
<input type="checkbox" name="room_type_uids[]" value="1" style="line-height: 8;height: 20px;"><span class="wrap_text">Double Bed</span><br />

.wrap_text {
   color: red;
}
```

---

If you do not want to assign a `class` to the `span` tag, you can also use adjacent selector `+` like

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/37yBh/)

```
input[name="room_type_uids[]"] + span {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the element with `<label>` which provide usability improvement. Style can be attached to label.

Example:

```
<label style="color:#FF0000;"><input type="checkbox" name="room_type_uids[]" value="1" style="line-height: 8;height: 20px;">Double Bed</label><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

see this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KNwuA/)**

you can not set style to "Double Bed" before that is not in a tag.

```
<span style="color:red">Double Bed</span>
```

for checkbox

you can add a **`vertical-align:middle`** style to your checkbox. so the checkbox align to middle.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="room_type_uids[]" value="1" style="line-height: 8;height: 20px; vertical-align:middle;">Double Bed<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Input element is not a **container element** and hence ***you can't control*** the styling or CSS rule for the text following the checkbox by defining style for the `<input type=checkbox>`-element.

You need a separate container that will contain the text and define style for the container itself to apply style on the text `"Double Bed"`.

So use the following:

```
<div style="line-height: 8;height: 20px;">
    <input type="checkbox" name="room_type_uids[]" value="1">Double Bed<br />
</div>
```